# In angular ui-grid how do I cancel a previously registered event?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

In Angular's ui-grid, the default behaviour is to queue the callbacks,
How would I cancel/overwrite the first callback ?

```
$scope.gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope, function(row){
    alert("Hello #1");
});

$scope.gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope, function(row){
    alert("Hello #2");
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to hang on to the destroyers that are returned when registering the events and then execute them.

As below

```
var hello1Destroyer = $scope.gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope, function(row){
    alert("Hello #1");
});

var hello2Destroyer = $scope.gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope, function(row){
    alert("Hello #2");
});
```

Somewhere you call `hello1Destroyer()` and `hello2Destroyer()`. You can put this on scope or just hang on to them in a certain scope.

Source: [Checkout official source master branch around line 278 inside feature.on[eventName] = function(){](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/blob/3b12b5cdada22aaccf479de6477a8fb3e26ee41e/src/js/core/factories/GridApi.js)

Comment: THIS WORKED! here is what I used:                                                       var destroyer = $scope.GeneralGridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope, function(a){
 alert("#1");
});

destroyer();

$scope.GeneralGridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope, function(a){
 alert("#2");
});

// the first callback is destroyed!!!

Comment: Great - just to make sure everything is ok check to see if you don't have any errors when the grid is destroyed. During destruction ui-grid will remove these listeners during scope $destroy cycle. Looking at their code it does not seem to be a problem.

Comment: @BrianJosephSpinos, please consider accept this answer if it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Their API page sucks to be honest. The way I came up with was to pass a function to the `rowSelectionChanged` and change that function later on like this:

PS: I know it is dirty but it works.

```
var handler = function(row) {
   alert("Hello #1");
}

$scope.gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope, handler);
```

Then later on you can change the handler:

```
handler = function(row) {
   alert("Hello #2");
}
```

Comment: Good Idea! I will try that!

Comment: var callback = function(a){
 alert("#1");
};

$scope.GeneralGridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope, callback);

callback = function(a){
 alert("#2");
};

$scope.GeneralGridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope, callback);